# How to tell whether zeros originate from trim or from actually writing zeros on an SSD

Tags: ssd, trim

Say if I write zero to a certain range of LBAs of a drive, then I TRIM those logical blocks (say, with blkdiscard or even hdparm). Given the drive has the Read Zero After TRIM behavior, is there a way for someone to tell whether the the logical blocks were TRIM'd or not?

(One way I could think of, which might work, could be a timed read to detect a faster response on trimmed data block than on a non-trimmed data block with all zeros, but this question is more about an API to just ask the disk.)

Comment: dont think its possible without directly accessing the SSD hardware.

Comment: Are you asking of the block in an SSD is trimmed and considered free by the ssd, or are you asking if a block in a file is a hole with no disk block associated with it?  The former is only relevant to block devices and free blocks in filesystems, not associated with files.  The latter is relevant to files but not SSDs or trim.   You seem to be confusing the two in your question.

Comment: AFAIK there's no command in the common protocols / command sets that allow you to check the logical-block-to-physical-block mapping. There might be "forensic" approach to communicate with the controller though, which I don't know of.

Comment: @user10489: I did ask exactly the question, I intended to ask. Now, I clarified the question. You assume, that trimming is irrelevant on allocated disk space. This assumption is wrong, which makes you jump to a wrong conclusion.

Comment: I don't think a sane filesystem would trim an allocated block.

Comment: @user10489: Ok, what does you make think, that not allocating blocks for zeros (i.e. creating a hole) is any more sane than actually allocating those blocks (like ext4 does) and then trimming them? Either way. This is not the question, I did not say, that any file system did something here.

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons (and bad ones) for writing zeros instead of a hole or creating a hole instead of writing zeros.  There is a long history in unix surrounding holes in files (usually involving random seeks and databases that store as sparse files), and I'm not aware of any unix that will create a hole if you explicitly write zeros.

Comment: Question changed as suggested by Tom Yan, it no longer mentions files at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, trim is not used for zeroing blocks.  Trim is used to tell an SSD that a block is no longer needed and its contents can be discarded.  The intent of trim is to actually help an SSD do write leveling by telling it that it can freely rewrite a block without first preserving its contents.  As such, it doesn't necessarily make sense to take an extra step to zero the block first.

The SSD trim standard states that reading a trimmed block will produce undefined results, rather than a zero block, although some versions of the standard do include a "read zero after trim" version of trim.  Since reading a trimmed block has undefined behavior, even ignoring cache issues, it is unlikely you will be able to tell if a block is trimmed by timing a read of it.  Writing to a trimmed block might not have a timing difference either, as write leveling might cause a different physical block to be written anyway.

Since trim is intended to discard blocks, a filesystem would not use trim on a block in a file -- but only on a block freed from a file.  So to ask if there is a way to tell if a block in a file has been trimmed makes no sense, because a filesystem would not do this to a file.   If you do have a filesystem with trimmed blocks in files, the filesystem is likely corrupt.  Even if you do have such a corrupt filesystem, the trim standard does not include any way to query if a block is trimmed, or even how many blocks on the SSD are trimmed.  A better question would be to ask if there is a way to determine if a block in a file is corrupt.  Some filesystems (e.g., zfs, others) do have this ability, but it may not be directly accessible outside of filesystem internals.  In a RAID, on reading a corrupt block, the raid *might* log this event, but will also reconstruct the block and likely rewrite a good block in its place.  If that fails, presuming the RAID doesn't just go offline, it might return an I/O error.

However if your filesystem is actually an image of a filesystem that is actually a file in another filesystem, fstrim can tell the operating system to release free blocks, which causes the underlying filesystem to actually create holes in the filesystem image file.  Unlike trim on SSDs, the behavior of holes in files is very well defined, and will always return zeros.  There are also (somewhat unportable) system calls that will allow a program to ask the filesystem where the holes in a file are.

Comment: For the record, even while quite many SATA SSDs do not advertise RZAT, the actual behavior is often at least *partially* RZAT. (For example, only the remainder that is smaller than certain granularity will be ignored; I've seen in some older case that even each TRIM range needs to align to that.) This *seems* to have changed in the case of NVMe btw, as the spec is apparently "deallocation"-aware by nature. The point is, the RZAT behavior does not (necessarily) rely on zeroing the actual memory. Rather it "deallocates" by "unmapping" LBA from that.

Comment: This really is an implementation detail and the standard leaves it up to the manufacturer to decide.  As such, behavior of these features has drifted over the years where the standard allows it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ask the question in a better way, by not involving file or filesystem at all, since that seems to be your actual intest:

> Say if I write zero to a certain range of LBAs of a drive, then I TRIM those logical blocks (say, with `blkdiscard`  or even `hdparm`). Given the drive has the *Read Zero After TRIM* behavior, is there a way for someone to tell whether the the logical blocks were TRIM'd or not?

And the answer (from me) is, unless the vendor provides some vendor-specific way to check the mapping of the logical blocks to the actual storage, or you manage to hack the controller by some means to do the equivalent, no, there's no standard way in common protocols / command sets for someone to tell *reliably*.

Comment: By the way, there's even a thing called "write same" in SCSI and recent ACS, which can be used to "write zero". Here I'm referring to "normal" write `dd`. Speaking of that, some SSD controller were known to "optimize" normal zero writing, IIRC...

Answer (score 1):

For NVME disks, there's a thing called *DULBE*, or *Deallocated or Unwritten Logical Block Error*. Here's a quote from chapter *3.2.3.2.1 Deallocated or Unwritten Logical Blocks* in [NVM Express® NVM Command Set Specification revision 1.0c October 3rd, 2022](https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM-Express-NVM-Command-Set-Specification-1.0c-2022.10.03-Ratified.pdf).

> Using the Error Recovery feature (refer to section 4.1.3.2), host software may select the behavior of the controller when reading deallocated or unwritten blocks. The controller shall abort Copy, Read, Verify, or Compare commands that include deallocated or unwritten blocks with a status of Deallocated or Unwritten Logical Block if that error has been enabled using the DULBE bit in the Error Recovery feature.

For certain NVME disk models that support this feature, it seems you can utilize it to retrieve whether one block is trimmed/unwritten or not.

But I don't know any model by which this feature is supported, at least not by `Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB` or `INTEL P4510 1TB`:

```sh
# nvme id-ns /dev/nvme0n1 -H | grep "Deallocated or Unwritten Logical Block error"
  [2:2] : 0     Deallocated or Unwritten Logical Block error Not Supported
```