# How quickly would TRIM make any data unrecoverable after you reset your PC?

Tags: windows

If you reset your PC, with an SSD using TRIM, how long would it take for all data to be unrecoverable? Talking about a simple ‘reset this pc’ not a secure erase.

Comment: Immediately. And already answered here https://superuser.com/questions/1835319/when-you-factory-reset-windows-does-it-clear-the-pagefile . Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Duplicates? That's a completely different question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRIM *should* make the data unrecoverable immediately by normal tools available to a user. As TRIM notifies the controller that blocks are no longer in use the SSD controller can remove the various links on the internal table that tells the it what data is linked where on the drive. Without those links the data read by the controller is essentially unknown.

In many cases controllers will return some fixed data that simply indicates an unallocated block, either zeroes, ones or some other fixed data. The behaviour is down to your specific SSD and the only way to know for certain is to test it yourself by writing some data to a specific block on disk, running TRIM and then reading that block.

From Chris Siebenmann [How secure is merely discarding (TRIMing) all of a SSD's blocks?](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/tech/SSDBlockDiscardHowSecure)

> any SSD you want to use today will support what's called 'Deterministic Read After TRIM (DRAT)' (sort of cf), where the SSD will always return a fixed result when you read data after a TRIM operation. Some SSDs also promise to always return zeros in this situation; this is 'Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM', variously abbreviated as 'DZAT', 'RZAT', or 'DRZAT'. These are the (S)ATA versions, but NVMe has a similar system. All of these mean that once you TRIM the entire drive, the previous data on the drive can't be read through normal means, so someone who gets your drive and puts it in a computer will get garbage

The page [Recovering Evidence from SSD Drives in 2014: Understanding TRIM, Garbage Collection and Exclusions](https://www.forensicfocus.com/articles/recovering-evidence-from-ssd-drives-in-2014-understanding-trim-garbage-collection-and-exclusions/) goes into even more detail on the pitfalls and problems of recovering data and even lists the command

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i trim
```

as a way (on Linux) to tell whether your drive will return some fixed block of data after a TRIM command. It should return something along the lines of `Deterministic read data after TRIM` which means that the controller will return specific data in the even of a TRIMed block being read.

That only applies to user tools though, the data is still written to the flash cells until some indeterminate time when the flash cells get erased by the controller. You could potentially remove the NAND flash device from the drive and do a raw read of it to recover data.

Manufacturers could also potentially put the drive into a mode whereby the controller passes through reads and writes directly to the flash cells, and therefore make it possible to recover the raw data, but this is very likely to be specific to a particular drive controller and manufacturer.

How long a time before the data is gone from the SSD flash storage is something that is going to be difficult to say. Garbage Collection is typically done when a drive is idle so simply leaving the drive powered on but unused should let the controller work and erase each flash cell, but it could be hours, days or weeks before *all* data is unrecoverable by any means.

Another question that goes into this at SuperUser is [How to tell whether zeros originate from trim or from actually writing zeros on an SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1652827/how-to-tell-whether-zeros-originate-from-trim-or-from-actually-writing-zeros-on)